# Specific keywords not working inside of a command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a "help" command for my bot and it works sometimes. Currently I'm having it find all the arguments of the message sent in discord, and right now I'm only having it console.log those arguments. For some reason when I do `-help hello` it will console.log `hello` but when I do `-help ban` it doesn't log anything and then the help command stops working. Here is my current code to find the arguments. `var args:any = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);` and then the actual help command itself

```
name: 'help',
description: "Provides more detail about commands",
async execute(message:any, args:any, Discord:any) {
    
    console.log(`args.length: ${args.length}`);
    console.log(args);
```

I'm wondering if there are specific words that don't work with Discord. Thanks :)

Comment: What's the point of using TypeScript if you type everything as "any"? If you were to take advantage of it's features you may have found bugs earlier

Comment: I wasn't aware that was a thing, my friend said to change it to typescript and I just kinda did, I didn't know there was anything like that. It still doesn't change the fact that for some reason this stuff doesn't work though

Comment: I'd recommend to stick to JavaScript if you're still learning and are opting out of *all* of Typescripts features. Regarding your issue, that's very weird. Your code shouldn't be changing behavior based on the content of a string unless you've otherwise written it to do so. Are you sure there isn't another command/procedure being ran when `ban` is your argument?

Comment: The only reason ban should be called is if it has the prefix in front which in this case it doesn't. Plus for some reason it works when I do `-help clear` which is another command I have. What are some of the benefits of typescript I'm missing out on cause I would like to keep it

Comment: Well, there's just not enough info here for us to be able to help you with your problem. None of the code provided in your question is causing this issue for you. As for the benefits of typescript, that's something for you to research on your own or ask people about on other platforms, not really a thing to be asking on Stack; some benefits include type-safety and easier documentation.

Comment: I can't find whats causing the problem though, it seems like thered be something wrong with the args section and how it's declared but I'm not sure